# Encoding decoded urls in c++

Tags: c++, unicode, character-encoding

I want to decode encoded urls. As an example the letter ö is encoded as `"%C3%B6"` corresponding to its hexadecimal utf-8 encoding `0xc3b6` (50102).

In need to know now how to print this value as ö on the console or into a string buffer.

Simply casting to char, wchar_t, char16_t or char32_t and printing to cout or wcout didn't work.

The closest I have got was by using its utf-16 representation `0x00f6`. The folowing code snippet prints ö

```
#include <codecvt>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

int main() {
  std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<char16_t>, char16_t> convert;
  std::cout << convert.to_bytes(0x00f6) << '\n';
}
```

I need now either a way to calculate `0x00f6` from `0xc3b6` or another approach to decode the url.

Comment: `'ö'` is mostly `'\x50\x102'`, so you won't have it in a char as is.

Comment: @Jarod42 Is it possible to have it in a string?

Comment: `ö` lies outside the ASCII range, therefore in either [precomposed or decomposed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precomposed_character) it'll take more than one byte. You must use a wide char like `L'ö'` or print it as a string instead of a char

Comment: @Jarod42 50102 is the decimal value. It's 0xC3B6 in hexadecimal which is the UTF-8 representation of [U+00F6](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00f6/index.htm)

Comment: @phuclv: Indeed, I use wrong values :-/ My point was mostly that multi byte character doesn't fit in one `char`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Is there a way to calculate `0x00f6` from `0xc3b6`? I couldn't find a relation between both Unicode representations. If there was one I could use the classes in `<codecvt>` to print `ö` from `0xc3b6`

Comment: Better to make it so that you don't have this multicharacter literal in the first place. What is it that you're trying to do?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I want to decode an encoded url where I have strings like %C3%B6 that I want to print as ö

Comment: @sv90 Right, that's far more interesting and does not resemble your current question at all. I suggest you edit it to describe the real problem.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks for the advice

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21216307/560648

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks but that UriHelper somehow didn't work for "%C3%B6"

Comment: Can't do much with the information "didn't work"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It printed `?` instead of `ö`

Comment: Just because you can decode a URL to a UTF-8 string doesn't guarantee that your console can display it properly. Also, there is no guarantee that a URL uses UTF-8 for encoding characters. The encoding of a URL is dependant on the server that the URL belongs to. This is a shortcoming that IRIs were designed to address when replacing URIs/URLs. Unicode is an after-thought in URLs, but is part of the design of IRIs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In POSIX you can print UTF8 string directly:

```
std::string utf8 = "\xc3\xb6"; // or just u8"ö"
printf(utf8);
```

In Windows, you have to convert to UTF16. Use `wchar_t` instead of `char16_t`, even though `char16_t` is supposed to be the right one. They are both 2 bytes per character in Windows.

You want `convert.from_bytes` to convert from UTF8, instead of `convert.to_bytes` which converts to UTF8.

Printing Unicode in Windows console is another headache. See relevant topics.

Note that `std::wstring_convert` is deprecated and has no replacement as of now.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <codecvt>
#include <windows.h>

int main() 
{
    std::string utf8 = "\xc3\xb6";

    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>, wchar_t> convert;
    std::wstring utf16 = convert.from_bytes(utf8);

    MessageBox(0, utf16.c_str(), 0, 0);
    DWORD count;
    WriteConsole(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), utf16.c_str(), utf16.size(), &count, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Encoding/Decoding URL

"URL safe characters" don't need encoding. All other characters, including non-ASCII characters, should be encoded. Example:

```
std::string encode_url(const std::string& s)
{
    const std::string safe_characters = 
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-._~";
    std::ostringstream oss;
    for(auto c : s) {
        if (safe_characters.find(c) != std::string::npos)
            oss << c;
        else
            oss << '%' << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << 
                std::uppercase << std::hex << (0xff & c);
    }
    return oss.str();
}

std::string decode_url(const std::string& s) 
{
    std::string result;
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
        if(s[i] == '%') {
            try { 
                auto v = std::stoi(s.substr(i + 1, 2), nullptr, 16);
                result.push_back(0xff & v);
            } catch(...) { } //handle error
            i += 2;
        }
        else {
            result.push_back(s[i]);
        }

    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the help. Here is what I have come up with. Maybe it will help someone else

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

#include <cstdint>

std::string encode_url(const std::string& s) {
  std::ostringstream oss;
  for (std::uint16_t c : s) {
    if (c > 0 && c < 128) {
      oss << static_cast<char>(c);
    }
    else {
      oss << '%' << std::uppercase << std::hex << (0x00ff & c);
    }
  }
  return std::move(oss).str();
} 

int parse_hex(const std::string& s) {
  std::istringstream iss(s);
  int n;
  iss >> std::uppercase >> std::hex >> n;
  return n;
}

std::string decode_url(const std::string& s) {
  std::string result;
  result.reserve(s.size());
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < s.size();) {
    if (s[i] != '%') {
      result.push_back(s[i]);
      ++i;
    }
    else {
      result.push_back(parse_hex(s.substr(i + 1, 2)));
      i += 3;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

There is still room for optimizations but it works :)

Comment: there's no need to do URL encode if you just want to print. URL encode has almost no usage outside of URLs

Comment: I did it only for completeness and testing :)

Comment: Your decode function should work fine. But the encode function can run in to trouble. For example `; / ? : @ = &` are reserved characters. See suggested answer.