# PostgreSQL - ECPG / C - host variable UTF-8 decoding

Tags: c, postgresql, utf-8, ecpg

I have a UTF8 encoding database.
I am using ECPG - PROGRAM C.

When I get data recordset with EXEC SQL

```
 EXEC SQL DECLARE cur_myTable CURSOR FOR
     SELECT code,
            label
     INTO  :hv_cod,
           :hv_label
     FROM  myTable
```

but I print data in the pgc file,

```
printf("\n libellé => %s", :hv_label ), I get:
```

I get :

```
libellé => tÃ©lÃ©.
```

Is it possible to UTF8 decode a host variable to ISO-8859-1 in a program C ?
Is it possible to say in the .pgc file : Postgres I want UTF8-decode values ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to UTF8 decode a host variable to ISO-8859-1 in a program C ?

Sure, lots of libraries do it. Look at `libiconv` for example.

> Is it possible to say in the .pgc file : Postgres I want UTF8-decode values ?

Trivially. [Set `client_encoding`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/multibyte.html) to `iso-8859-1` or whatever your local encoding is. You can [do this with libpq functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-control.html); ecpg may have its own equivalents, not sure.

Comment: Hi Craig ! thank you, I found what I need at [UTF8 decoding](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11173493/3318639) in C language, but ecpg does not have equivalents.

Comment: Oh man, Postgres is so cool ! NO NEED for UTF8 decoding or encoding, I found an easier solution : in the pgc file, just say : EXEC SQL SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO "ISO-8859-1"; It doesn't matter what database encoding is and it works ! so cool !